# Thinking Sphinx and negative IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a `User`model and a `Message` model where users can send messages to each other, and I use [Thinking Sphinx gem](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/) for fulltext search as connector for [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) in Ruby on Rails.

In my `User` model I use negative IDs for system users, positive IDs for regular users.

Now I have the problem that Sphinx seems to ignore searches in messages by/to users with those negative IDs (=foreign key `sender_id` as `has`-Attribute).

Index as definded in my `Message` model:

```
define_index 'messages_index' do
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes body

  has sender_id, recipient_id, created_at, updated_at
end
```

The search is done in the `MessagesController`:

```
@received_messages = current_user.received_messages.search params[:q]
```

If the `current_user` has a negative ID no result is returned. When I do a `reindex` it shows that all Sphinx collected all messages, none were left out.

Is there any way to teach Sphinx to accept negative numbers for `has`-Attributes? Or ideas for any work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx's integer type is unsigned, so your negative values aren't collected.

You could force the type to be a float, but don't forget to make any filters on those attributes floats as well:

```
has sender_id, recipient_id, :type => :float
has created_at, updated_at
```

Comment: Did not know that the `:type` can be set per attribute, this is not mentioned in the docs?! I used `:type => :bigint` which is working fine, and gives no problems that `:float` might have with integer values. Great thanks!